# Find Randomart of existing ssh key

Tags: ssh, encryption

I created an ssh key with `ssh-keygen`, and I got this output as a result:

```
The key fingerprint is:
84:21:3d:ab:d5:5e:05:a0:b6:ab:0f:33:af:3b:3b:82 cidr@randombox
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 4048]----+
|             .ooo|
|       o   ..o   |
|      o + .oo .  |
|     . + o....   |
|    +...S  ..    |
|       .o   .    |
|    .  o o ..    |
|   E . .o +      |
|      ......     |
+-----------------+
```

Is there a way to view the randomart image of an existing key?  (Also, what's the purpose of randomart in connection to ssh or cryptography?)

Comment: Wondering about 4048: Did you mean 4096? It seems like you got a "numeric portmanteau" of 2048 and 4096.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this:

```
ssh-keygen -lv -f .ssh/id_rsa
```

This can be found in ssh-keygen's manpage.
As for randomart's purpose:

"The randomart is meant to be an easier way for humans to validate keys.

Validation is normally done by a comparison of meaningless strings (i.e. the hexadecimal representation of the key fingerprint), which humans are pretty slow and inaccurate at comparing. Randomart replaces this with structured images that are faster and easier to compare."

This text was taken from here: https://superuser.com/questions/22535/what-is-randomart-produced-by-ssh-keygen

Comment: Thannks a lot buddy, this helps a lot :)

Comment: For more explanation of situations for use, [see the SU discussion](http://superuser.com/a/22541/69570)

Comment: Please note that it works also for `id_rsa.pub` file: `ssh-keygen -lv -f .ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: Beware that the randomart generated by older versions of `ssh-keygen` (say from openSSH_6.6.1p1) will not match that of newer ones (say from openSSH_7.1p2). If the openSSH package-versions differ between your client and server, consider upgrading or checking out [workarounds](http://superuser.com/questions/929566/).

Comment: Super helpful, thank you! If only I could upvote twice